# Why don't we decompose all relations into 2-attribute relations?

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

Relations having only 2 attributes are in BCNF.

> Why don't we decompose all relations into 2-attribute relations?
>
> Because if we do so, we cannot achieve lossless join.

What is an example of decomposing a relation into 2-attribute relations where when we join them data is lost?

Comment: You seem to assume that all candidate keys have one column. That's not the case. But you *can* decompose relations into a candidate key and no more than one non-prime attribute. Search term is "6NF" or "sixth normal form".

Comment: This is not clear. "Relations having only 2 attributes are in BCNF"--False. "So" What do you mean, "So"? What does the 1st line it have to do with the rest of the post? "Because if we do so, we cannot achieve lossless join" Sometimes we can. Maybe you mean something like, because sometimes there is no lossless join"? But if sometimes there isn't, so what? "an example of that answer" What do you mean by an example of a "because ..."?? This post wanders unclearly & unexplained through claims & Q&A & hypotheticals. What 1 thing are you trying to ask? To ask for an example give its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can't decompose a table to 2 attributes based on the functional dependencies, a classical example my professor always uses is city, state, zipcode
`FD{ city, state -> zip, zip->city}`
Decomposing relationship R(city, state,zipcode) would not have dependency preservation.
Ex. You can't have the two tables R(city, state) and S(zip,city) because city,state is a super key but it doesn't determine zip in table R

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's obvious that BCNF cannot preserve dependency, even if we decompose the relation into 2-attribute relations or not. Using BCNF decomposition algorithm still cannot achieve dependency preservation.

Comment: BCNF can preserve dependency, it just doesn't guarantee it, it depends on the set of functional dependencies

Comment: Yes, but here I don't care about the dependency. My problem is lossless join. Could you give me an example that when we join decomposed relations (2-attributes relations), we cannot get the original one due to data lost?

Comment: I thought your question was "Why don't we decompose all relations into 2-attribute relations?"

Comment: To answer your question though BCNF guarantees lossless join, so if you decompose "intelligently" you will have lossless join, i.e not data lost

Comment: However if you have R(A,B,C,D) and you decompose to R(A,B) S(C,D) then there is no join possible

Comment: No, if you decompose the relation R(A,B,C,D) into 2-attribute relations, the decomposed relations should be: R(A,B), S(B,C), T(C,D).